# Cannot run Jar file via .sh script on Mac OS X

Tags: bash, terminal, executable-jar

Open up terminal, and type:

```
java -jar ./program.jar
```

Works fine. When I open Sublime editor and type this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Running program..."
java -jar ./program.jar
```

And save as: **run.sh**

Right-mouse click on **run.sh**, Show info, Open with **Terminal (2.6)**. Now double-click it:

```
Running program...
Error: Unable to access jarfile program.jar
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add to the bash script `echo $PWD` - the script apparently run from different directory and can't find the `program.jar` file. In the script, either add `cd <dir-with-jar>` or use the absolute path to `program.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

Just put in the absolute path of the jar file or `cd` into that directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /path/to/jar/file
echo "Running program..."
java -jar ./program.jar
```

Comment: Okay, that works, thanks! But I would like to deliver this to different users so that they can just double-click the .sh file. I don't know their directories. So is there another way for this?

Comment: If you pack the jar and the .sh script into on archive, you can remove "cd /path/to/jar/file". Then when the user unpacks the achive the files will be in the same directory and "java -jar ./program.jar" will work. You could also say "java -jar $(pwd)/program.jar" which will call the jar with absolute url.